# Index an array by an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

In R you can do something like this:

```
> x = c(1, 222, 333, 4, 5)
> x[c(2, 3)]
[1] 222 333
```

`>` in the beginning of line is just a prompt in an interactive session. x is a vector of numeric values, and if you want the 2nd and 3rd element of x, you pass another vector c(2, 3) to index x. This is different from Arrays.copyOfRange in java: you can pass an arbitrary index vector to x, not necessarily in a continuous range, i.e. x[c(1,3,5)]

I am wondering if there is a similar feature in java.

Comment: Can you explain what's the desired behavior? I don't know R.

Comment: If you take a minute to explain what does this mean in R you increase your chance to get response from people that are not familiar with R but familiar with java.

Comment: It's still not clear. Are (1,2,3,4,5) the values of the array x? Or are they indices of the array? And what does the output [1] 2 3 mean?

Comment: x is an array of numeric values, called numeric vector in R.

Comment: I need to ask, does `R` have indices from `1` or from `0`? The arrays in Java start indices from `0`.

Comment: @Eran output is an vector of two elements, i.e. the 2nd and 3rd of x, which we asked for by doing x[c(2,3)]

Answer (score 3):

As I understood your question, you could create a method that take a list of indexes as parameters.

For generic arrays, you'll need to use `Array.newInstance` and cast the resulting array to `T[]` (thanks and kudos for @Radiodef for pointing this out)

```
//for lists
static <T> List<T> buildList(List<T> original, int... indexes){
    List<T> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int index : indexes){
        finalList.add(original.get(index));
    }
    return finalList;
}

//for arrays
static <T> T[] buildArray (T[] original, int... indexes){       
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] finalArray = (T[])Array.newInstance(original.getClass().getComponentType(), indexes.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++){
        finalArray[i] = original[indexes[i]];
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

Few notes :

- For primitive arrays (like `int[]` or `double[]`), you'll have to overload the methods, that's why I suggest you to use a `List` with generics instead.
- Indexes for arrays in Java are 0 based (starts from 0 to length-1)
- Don't forget to add additional checks for the method (valid index, original list or index not null)
- If you use a `LinkedList` instead of an `ArrayList`, be aware that `#get(int index)` is an O(n) operation instead of O(1)

Example of usage :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] xArray = {-1, 10, 24, 7};
    List<Integer> xList = Arrays.asList(-1, 10, 24, 7);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buildArray(xArray, 0, 2)));
    System.out.println(buildList(xList, 0, 1, 3));
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[-1, 24]
[-1, 10, 7]
```

Comment: Your generic `buildArray` for `T[]` is incorrect. You need to use `Arrays.copyOf` or `Array.newInstance`. You can't do `(T[])new Object[n]` in a context where the array is returned. It will throw an exception.

Comment: @Radiodef Why would it throw an Exception?

Comment: Because you are casting `Object[]` to `T[]`!! Try this: `String[] arr = buildArray(new String[]{"a", "b"}, 0, 1);`

Comment: @Radiodef Hmm you are right, let me rethink this. :)

Comment: Just use [`Array#newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-) as in `(T[])Array.newInstance(original.getClass().getComponentType(), indexes.length)`. Your answer is otherwise good.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Arrays.copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T[],%20int,%20int%29)